# String alligment issues on parser's output file

Tags: python, string-formatting

I recently started making a parser to read some data from a .txt file and writing the info in another file but I'm having issues with the output. For example when I open the file where the parser wrote the info it looks like this

```
House 9 = 130 square feet
House 10 = 140 square feet
```

All the houses before house number 10 have one less space because the number of the house is only one digit, therefore when you open the output file the area of those houses appear to be shifted one by one space to the left and it does not look like a uniform output, I solved the problem with and if statement but my supervisor told me to use String formatting to solve the issue but so far I  haven't been able to do so. Is there a way to get the output looking like this using string formatting instead of if statements ?

```
House 9  = 130 square feet
House 10 = 140 square feet
```

That the numbers of the area are aligned is what I mean

In case it help I'm using python 2.7

Comment: show us the code of the parser...

Comment: you can align numbers and strings with ljust and rjust. Something like this should do the trick: `str(your_number).rjust(15)`. The 15 says, that python extends the content to fill 15 characters in total.

Answer (score 1):

use st like this:

```
print('{:10s} {:3d}  {:7.2f}'.format('aaa', 123, 98))
print('{:10s} {:3d}  {:7.2f}'.format('bbbb', 5, 1.0))
print('{:10s} {:3d}  {:7.2f}'.format('cc', 44, 123.34))
```

output:

```
aaa        123    98.00
bbbb         5     1.00
cc          44   123.34
```